# Joomla 3 How to Style PHP Date Format

Tags: php, css, date, joomla, joomla3.0

Hello I want to ask how to add style to Date Format in Joomla 3 mod_articles_category/default.php.

The code:

```html
<?php echo $item->displayDate; ?>
```

produce this as result in one line:

```html
<span class="mod-articles-category-date">2015-10-14 16:24:53</span>
```

2015-09-21 20:52:35

What The Result in Front Page Module Right Now: [image]

And I don't want this because I want to style (add CSS) to each date, month, and year separately. And I also want to remove the time too.

What I'm trying to do like in Category Blog Layout:
[image]

Please help, any advice will be greatly appriciated. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to configure, inside your module administration panel go to the "display options" (before advanced) and change the date format.

Follow this http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php to see all the available options.

If you prefer a more interesting module you can try with this: http://mapkcode.com/demo-mk-extensions/mk-advanced-articles

This module works like the mod_articles_category but give your lot of parameters, 10+ styles and works perfectly with bootstrap.

Cheers,
Marco

Comment: Where are you seeing the `option visualization` tab? This is not a default tab in Joomla.

Comment: "Display options" - in module Articles Category

Comment: Hi again Marco thanks again for helping me the second time, cheers! ^.^ I tried the guide you told me about how to change the date format in the "Display Options" Module. It worked as charm. But i'm still trying to figure out how to style the output because it's still looked like <span class="mod-articles-category-date">21 Sep 2015</span> and I can't style the date and month separately. Will try tweaking again and if I still unable to do it, I will try the MK Advanced Articles module you told me. I guess the mod_articles_category is givin me a headache for it's little customization @.@

Comment: You can try with a trick. Use the item->displaydate twice. For each one give its own span class, moreover use the php substr to filter the output so that one will display only the day, second only the month (or whatever you want)   other solution is to use php split function to divide each field day, month, year

Comment: Finally it worked. At first I didn't understand because I am not PHP savvy, but I decided to google it out to find examples. Now I can finally style the output using the trick you've told me. <span class="date"><?php echo substr($item->displayDate, 0,2); ?></span> <br> <span class="month"><?php echo substr($item->displayDate, 2,5); ?></span> It works like charm and I can get the displaydate layout that I truly want. So many thank you again Marco for your help.